# For the umpteenth time: CSS, *auto-sized* header and 100% height content

Tags: html, css

Here's what I am looking to achieve. I have HTML along those lines (in reality I use a separate CSS file of course):

```
    <div id="container" style="position:absolute; left:20px; top:20px; height:300px; width:400px;">
        <div id="header" style="width:100%;">header stuff here...</div>
        <div id="content">content stuff here...</div>
    </div>
```

I want header to be **auto** sized with respect to height and the rest of the parent div to be occupied by content. The content should fill exactly - no scrollbars or anything. Assume modern browsers, I don't care about IE6 or even IE7.

All the examples I've seen so far assume fixed header height. Can auto-sized header be achieved without JavaScript, or is it beyond capabilities of modern browsers?

Comment: you can place an image tag inside head with width 100% and then the img tag will auto scale header itself. But i do not know if your design allows it

Comment: Are you trying to make the header grow dynamically vertically(height), while pushing down the content below it and the #container growing in height to accommodate the growing content?

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle of the provided code](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/FuUSX/). Everyone can edit its styles to try to get the CSS that Ivan is asking for.

Comment: Container size is fixed - no growing. Header size is also fixed, but I don't know what it is, neither in pixels nor percentage of the total height. Think of an h1 tag inside header - the actual size will vary with font.

Comment: Ivan, you say no scroll bars. So what if there is too much content? For instance, what if the header is 100px tall and the content is 400px tall? That will not fit in the 300px container. Should the content be cut off, or should the whole page get a scroll bar, or just the content get a scroll bar?

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov I still don't understand exactly what you want. Can you answer my scroll bar question? I might be able to figure out a CSS-only solution.

Comment: I would expect the content to be cut off. Ability to add an "auto" scroll bar only for content if necessary would be nice, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hYhVa/1/) or [its output](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hYhVa/1/show/). Try resizing the window.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="header" style="width:100% ">some stuff here...</div>
    <div id="content">ome other stuff here...</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var header_height = $("#header").height();
    var content_height = $("body").height() - header_height;
    $("#content").height(content_height);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    var header_height = $("#header").height();
    var content_height = $("body").height() - header_height;
    $("#content").height(content_height);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#header {
    height: auto;
    background-color: green;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The JS helps the content div to take all the available space even when we resize the window :)

Comment: I don't think this is what Ivan wants. You have changed the container height to 100%. But Ivan said in a comment, "Container size is fixed - no growing". I think he wants the container to always have 300px height like in his example code.

Comment: OH! He want's the header to be 100%?

Comment: Thanks, Mohammad. I know this can be done with JavaScript, but the sample is still definitely a good thing. The question is, however, can it be done with just CSS? Do you imply that the answer is "no"?

Comment: Yes, I did not ask for 100% body height. But it does not matter much anyway - I wanted to avoid writing a synchronizing Javascript.

Comment: @IvanKrivyakov yes, the answer is "no" because this needs some basic maths which CSS doesnot know how to do but I would recommend you using LESS or SASS/SCSS. AT LEAST YOU CAN GIVE ME A +1 ? No?

Comment: +1: certainly. Let's wait what other people have to say, this might as well be the answer.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui If this style is not possible with plain CSS, then I don’t think LESS or Sass will help. They both compile to plain CSS. And since Ivan doesn’t know the height of the header when he’s writing the stylesheets, he can’t use LESS and Sass’s calculation feature. Their calculations happen at compile time, but the height is known only at run time (in the browser).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with CSS after all. You need to use `display:table` and have the content pane height at 100%. Unfortunately, you will also need an extra <div> inside header and content. JSFiddle link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/RBHXm/3/. You may also add footer if you'd like: http://jsfiddle.net/DE8pA/3/

You will also need to introduce padding to prevent [margin collapse](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/). Otherwise things like <h1> will look funny.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header" ><div><h1>Header stuff<br />here...</h1></div></div>
    <div id="content"><div><p>content stuff here...</p></div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* colors to make the demo clear: */
#container { background: #ddd; }
#header { background: #ddf; }
#content { background: #dfd; }

/* CSS provided in question: */
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
}

/* your fix: */
#container {
    display: table;
}

#container > * {
    display: table-row;    
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
}

#container > * > * {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0.01px;
}

/* optional styles to make it look pretty */
#content > div {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px;
    color: blue;
}
```